# Rspec error message: PagesController GET 'home'' has should have the right title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

```
  Error Message:PageController GET 'contact' should have the right title....
```

I would like to ask for an advice with more experienced Rubists. I am following rails tutorial 3 by Michael Hartl and  just before the end of Chapter 3 I have the error message enclosed.

I really do not know what to change as I checked several times and my files are the same as in the textbook.

My codes are available at Github:
https://github.com/maro9/sample_app

Thank you in advance for any help.

Error message printscreen:
http://s11.postimage.org/pcz9us1tv/rspec_error.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, your "App" in the content is lower case, but you are testing against capitalized.

What you're created

```
"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample app | About"
```

What you're asserting you created

```
"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About"
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb should change by:

```
-            <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample app | <%= @title %></title>
+            <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= @title %></title>
```

Comment: Just by mistake. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
response.should have_selector("title",
                :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App|Home")
```

to this:

```
response.should have_selector("title",
                :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
```

in your `pages_controller_spec.rb`: https://github.com/maro9/sample_app/blob/master/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb#L15

Comment: Hello Agis, thanks for advice...I tried it but it does not work. Still have error message. See my commit on Github: https://github.com/maro9/sample_app/commit/f84297510722ca1db54cd58f8c31aefd9752d0ce